# Changing variable of an array within while loop not working

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I have a piece of sample code and was wondering what i could do to change the output.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
int input;
string stat[2];
stat[0] = "a";
stat[1] = "b";
int j = 0;
int h = 0;
int i = 0;
while(h < 4){
    i=0;
    cout << stat[0] << endl;
    cout << stat[1] << endl;
    string stat[2];
    stat[0] = "c";
    stat[1] = "d";
    cout << stat[0] << endl;
        cout << stat[1] << endl;
        h++;
    }
}
```

The current output is:
a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d

My desired output is:
a,b,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d,c,d

Comment: You have two different `stat` variables. Why? That will only lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your program and now it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string stat[2] = {"a","b"};
   int h = 0;
   while(h++ < 4)
   {
      cout << stat[0] << endl;
      cout << stat[1] << endl;
      stat[0] = "c";
      stat[1] = "d";
      cout << stat[0] << endl;
      cout << stat[1] << endl;
   }
}
```

The problem was that in the while loop you were declaring a new array of strings with the same name of the array outside so your reference to the first array was removed. Finally i have removed i and j because you are't using it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second string in a loop

```
while(h < 4){
    i=0;
    cout << stat[0] << endl;
    cout << stat[1] << endl;
    stat[0] = "c";
    stat[1] = "d";
    cout << stat[0] << endl;
        cout << stat[1] << endl;
        h++;
    }
```